# Non-violent uses of a dragon?

Tags: science-based, medieval, dragons

So, back to my acid-breathing (sulfuric acid, pH 0.2-0.1, 1-3 liters can be stored at a time) dragon.

So, the Dragon's life isn't exactly great, he's currently a slave working for a larger town, he previously raided for food (nothing really fancy, just snuck in and stole a handful of apples a few times).

Only five people consider him to be (gasp) a living and feeling creature, plus he has to risk his life on a regular basis during military campaigns.

What about peacetime then? I mean, the setting has times of peace, though ceasefire would be a better term. What would the Dragon do then? More precisely, what would they make the Dragon do then?

Doing some helpful work would theoretically be good at convincing the already extremely racist Church that the Dragon is not the reincarnation of Trash Man (this world's equivalent of Satan), or at least it's a safer attempt than the time they gave the Dragon an educational tour around fantasy Vatican, which nearly ended in bloodshed.

The world itself is your average perma-medieval world with lots of zombies walking around during night. They aren't bright or strong, but there's a lot of them.

Zombies are grown in the tubers of a very abundant plant, making them extremely numerous. Acid is effective against them, but overall, it's really not worth fighting them, as walls are enough to keep them out.

---

The Dragon is a hexapodal, warm-blooded creature with an extremely long lifespan. He stands squarely 2 meters at the shoulders, but is less bulky than a horse of that size, and has a vent-snout length of 5 meters. His laterally compressed tail is half the total body length (so, also five meters). You really don't want to get whipped by it.

### Hardiness

The dragon's body is covered in red scales, which provide ample protection against swords maces and even guns, as well as against the dragon's own acid. Of course, he isn't invincible. Sufficient force, the right disease or simple tiredness can still get him.

### Flight

While it seems unlikely for a creature with that dimensions to be able to fly, it's sort of manageable. Pterosaurs like the Hatzegopteryx and Quetzalcoatlus grew way beyond previously believed size limits. There are two big factors, as far as I can see, that limit a dragon's size. First is the strength of the materials that the wings and the rib cage are made out of, which we could improve without adding extra weight. Second is the food source.

Putting it together, this means that the Dragon can't use powered flight (and thus, take off) frequently. Once in the air, he can use thermals to gain altitude and travel long distances without expending energy. Flight speed is 16.3 - 24.9 m/s. Terrestrial capabilities are good, but overall strength obviously suffers because of the high mass fraction of the flight muscles.

### Senses

As far as senses go, the Dragon has a good (dog levels of good) sense of smell, complete with a Jacobson's Organ. Hearing is decent, eyesight is very good, on pair with golden eagles. He possesses nictitating membranes and is able to seal his nose (like otters) and hold breath for a while (thanks to the abundance of air sacs).

---

"Wow, this dragon seems pretty OP, how could they even make him a slave?", you might be asking. The answer is one half death threats, in the form of the aforementioned disease and "dragon-slaying" weapons, contaminated with it.

The second half is magic, namely, very rare *compulsion spell* that makes the Dragon carry out the orders of his superiors in an unconscious/sleepwalking state, if he doesn't do it out of his "free will". Note that the spell activates only when he's defying direct orders.

For conflicting orders, the one issued by the higher authority figure takes precedence and feasibility takes precedence over authority, if the order is impossible to carry out.

In practice, if he's tasked with bringing "Piggy" (how he calls <s>Robert Baratheon</s> the king) his breastplate stretcher, he can curse like a sailor on the way, as long as he's making progress towards retrieving the item. Having to go (fly) to the nearest bathroom is considered backwards progress, so it causes the spell to activate, but only when the Dragon used up all his "potty tickets" a set number of times he can go to the bathroom, though the spell can still trigger there, if he isn't making progress towards... relieving himself.

**Given this information, what non-violent, civil job would be the most suitable (i.e: take the most advantage of the unique perks) for the Dragon?**

The job should be one that a dragon can do in a different and miles better way, compared to humans, and is of the most use for the community.

Comment: Here's a joke: Q: Where does a 800-pound gorilla sit? A: Anywhere it wants to, it's an 800-pound gorilla. Follow-up joke: Q: What does a dragon do with his spare time? A: Anything it wants to, it's a *dragon*. No one's going to stop it. If it want to sew buttons, it's going to sew buttons and no one will dare to protest.

Comment: Which acid(s)? What is it's Ph?

Comment: I'm having a problem reconciling your description of the dragon's physical attributes with the idea of it being a slave.  It seems like a very unlikely creature to be made a slave in the first place, but just as hard (and very dangerous) to keep a slave.

Comment: Aright, nobody move. I've got a dragon and I'm not afraid to use it.

Comment: Halfthawed, @StephenG the whole concept behind this question is that the dragon does *not* have freedom. It doesn't matter *why* it's a slave; just that it is.

Comment: @SEistoopoliticallycorrect Well, too late.

Comment: @Mephistopheles I loaded the page before you're update; as a result, I didn't see it until *after* I did the comment. If you're referring to the downvote, on the other hand, that wasn't me; I was the one who did an upvote.

Comment: @SEistoopoliticallycorrect Nah, I was talking about the edit. I wanted to make some rules for the dragon's compulsion spell anyways.

Comment: @Mephistopheles That makes sense. By the way, I really like your questions, and from what I can tell it is shaping up into a really good book. Do you mind putting up a Meta post about it when you're done? I would like to read it.

Comment: Flagging for too-opinon-based.

Comment: Crossing guard?

Comment: @SEistoopoliticallycorrect You are entitled to your viewpoint, but slave is a problem term as the conditions (including the social attitudes to dragons as non-slaves) is rather significant if you want the dragon to find a role in a society.  There's a difference between the dragon's slavery being an exception to the rule or the norm.  A rather obvious role would be acid maker in this case.  Lot's of uses for acids and depending on what acid the creature creates it could be an important source.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this query not as broad as an infinite plane? Basically, the dragon could be employed anywhere any kind of heat, flame or fire is required from camp counsellor specialising in smores to hypocaustic engineer to hiring himself for barbecues and cook-offs. VTC.

Comment: @elemtilas Try cooking with sulfuric acid.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that bit! Just replace "heat" with "acid wash" and the result is the same...

Comment: **What should the dragon do that's "the most use for the community"?** seems to be the question. What do they need sulphuric acid *for*? (Is it even slightly effective against zombies? Are the zombies a hazard anyhow or just an eyesore?) How fast can the dragon produce more? Why isn't it just easier to make the acid through alchemy to save on the overhead of feeding/training and coping with the waste of a dragon? Your edit doesn't make the question less broad.

Answer (score 3):

## **Sounds like a perfect messenger/mail 'dragon'!**

Train the dragon to fly through a specific round-trip route that reaches multiple cities. Have a spotter look out for the dragon in every city. When the dragon is coming onto a city, hoist a long pole with a bag at the end, preferably at a high location like a top of the hill or a castle. The dragon can drop whatever it has on the city, and swoop in to grab the new bag hoisted in the air. The dragon can fly onto the next city and repeat.

You can then designate several cities where the dragon can land and rest and be fed at, so that the dragon can do these tasks everyday.

There would be no need for postriders that can be attacked by zombies and raiders. There would be no need for bird carriers that can be attacked by predators. A dragon is faster, carries a lot more, can't be attacked (probably), and can travel longer distances. It's a perfect messenger!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this dragon has the dreadful position of having to get rid of the dead. You mentioned acid - that can be used to make sure those pesky humans stay dead.